# GHCI: ghc-options for test suite overriding ghc-options for library

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, ghci

I have a library being compiled with `-Wall`, and I have a test suite with `-Wall -Wno-incomplete-patterns`

When I fire up ghci with `stack ghci --test`, it seems ghci picks the ghc options from the test suite and applies them to both projects.
In other words, it applies `-Wno-incomplete-patterns` to the library code as well.

Is there a way of stopping ghci from doing that?

Comment: Does your test suite include your library in its `build-depends`, or does it just import stuff and share the same `hs-source-dirs`? (If you don't know, include your cabal file in the question; the answer is in there, and I know how to extract it.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, the test suite depends on the library. I've uploaded the cabal file here: https://gist.github.com/dcastro/7efac2b2db024451eea26687bf135890

Comment: If it helps, the actual project is here: https://github.com/dcastro/haskell-flatbuffers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just removing the flag from the test suite and adding it on a per-module basis:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-incomplete-patterns #-}
```

Not a proper fix, but worked for this simple scenario.